# Custom conditional tags in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags, conditional-statements

all of you knows the conditional tags in wordpress , they are like this :

```
is_archive () , is_single()
```

now im looking for a conditional tag to check if the archive page of a term or a list of terms being displayed. something like this :

```
is_archive($term_name) OR is_archive(array(term1,term2,term3))
```

and my question is that , `is wordpress have a conditional tag for this functionality ?` or `are we can create a new conditional tag in wordpress ?`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can see the full list of conditional tags [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

There is `is_tag`, used as such:

```
is_tag( array( 'sharp', 'mild', 'extreme' ) )
```

These functions return true, so you can use them like below to build up more complex conditions:

```
if (is_archive($term_name) || is_tag( array( 'sharp', 'mild', 'extreme' ) ) {
 // do something
}
```

Comment: thanks , but the `is_archive($term_name)` don't given any argument's please read its codex first